# Unable to ESRI Javascript API and html2canvasa to print off map div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arcgis-js-api

I have not been able to get html2canvas to work with the ESRI Javascript API interface. It will print everything as seen on the page properly except the map content.

Has anyone been able to figure out how to make this work and if so can you provide an example?

If you have not been able to make this work, what solution did you use to create a screen capture of the entire page for your user to properly print off what they are viewing?

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLj11qva/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about your specific use case, I'd guess that the map is composed of images hosted on a different domain than your site. So, html2canvas is most likely running into the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and can't read those images.

From the html2canvas documentation:

"All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas."

They do have options for setting a proxy to get cross-origin images though, as well as an option for trying to load images with CORS headers. Check the "proxy" and "useCORS" options in their [documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you by chance know how to correct an issue with it for opacity. I asked on GitHub as well, but maybe you have a solution for it as well: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/672